# CFWheels findAll Group By Having Clause

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

In CFWheels I am looking at the findAll() page and it has a group by option by doesn't have a Having Clause option. Is there a way to use having clause using findAll() in CFWheels.

Comment: Did you try adding the having clause in `group` itself? Like
`group="name having age>20"`

Comment: @Pankaj Yes, it did work. checklist = model("user_checklist").findAll(select="MAX(user_checklist.r_id)", group="r_id HAVING MAX(user_checklist.r_id) > 13");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to share. Credit to Pankaj in the comment for his answer. Thank you

```
checklist = model("user_checklist").findAll(select="MAX(user_checklist.r_id)", group="r_id HAVING MAX(user_checklist.r_id) > 13");
```

gives you

```
SELECT MAX(user_checklist.r_id) FROM user_checklist GROUP BY r_id HAVING MAX(user_checklist.r_id) > 13
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very disappointing that the dynamic filtering of the grouped data is not available even in the new release `CFWheels 1.4.2`.

What I found is [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/cfwheels/issues/detail?id=785), it is a very old issue posted under the cfwheels google group and [a google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cfwheels/_-53n7Zb_Hc). Even to this day the workaround for using a `having` in the `group by` statement is to use the [**cfrel**](https://github.com/dhumphreys/cfrel) by [dumphreys](https://github.com/dhumphreys) which is a ColdFusion Relational Algebra Framework.

I would recommend trying it, it is very easy to use and cleanly written.  If you navigate to `cfrel.cfc` you would find a `findAll()` function which looks similar to the original `findAll()` in cfwheels (*check out the \wheels\model\read.cfm*), but there you'll find it supports `having()` right out of the box.

Example (cfrel having clause):

```
    /*  
    SQL: SELECT productId, SUM(total) AS totalSum FROM orders
         GROUP BY productId HAVING SUM(total) > ?
         ORDER BY totalSum DESC LIMIT 5
    PARAMS: [1000]
    */
    myOrdersRel = relation(datasource="cfrel")
        .select("productId,SUM(total) AS totalSum")
        .from("orders")
        .group("productId")
        .having("SUM(total) > ?", [1000])
        .order("totalSum DESC")
        .limit(5);
    query2 = rel2.query();
```